# Conversor en js de euro

Tags: javascript, array

Buenos días soy nuevo programando y tengo esta tarea

Un cliente desea dar el cambio exacto mínimo en monedas de euros. Realice una función en JS que al ingresar un string con un monto la misma devuelva un arreglo con las monedas a entregar.

Ejemplo
`const x = darCambio("2.34")`

`console.log(x) // devuelve [2,0.2,0.1,0.02,0.02]`
Las monedas de euro son:
2 , 1, 0.50 , 0.20 , 0.10 , 0.05 , 0.02 , 0.01
no sé como hacerlo bien, dado que no le he entendido al profesor, alguien que por favor me explique bien como hacer el ejercicio gracias.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Convertidor</title>
        <input type="number" id="moneda">
        <input type="submit" id="convertir" value="convertir">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    </body>
    <script>
        const convertir = document.getElementById('convertir')
        convertir.addEventListener("click", () => {
            let moneda = document.getElementById("moneda");
            let valor = moneda.value;
            alert(`El valor del es: ${Math.floor(valor)}`)
        })
    </script>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: podrias publicar la funcion o todo tu codigo?

Comment: Hola @JhonnattanRivera ahí coloque mi código

Comment: pero debes tener un array que almacene cuantas monedas y de que valor posees, pues puede que la maquina no las tenga.

Comment: si eso es lo qué estoy intentando y no entiendo bien como hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    function redondear1(numero) {
        return Math.sign(numero) * Math.floor(Math.abs(numero) + 0.5);
    }
    function redondear(numero, digitos) {
        let base = Math.pow(10, digitos);
        let entero = redondear1(numero * base);
        return entero / base;
    }
    function cambio(valor = 0, monedas = []) {
        i = 1 + monedas.length;
        let cambio = monedas.map(() => 0);
        for (let j = 0; j < monedas.length; j++) {
            i++;
            cambio[j] = Math.floor(valor / monedas[j]);
            valor = redondear(valor % monedas[j], 2);
            if (valor === 0) break;
        }
        return cambio;
    }
    const convertir = document.getElementById('convertir')
    convertir.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let moneda = document.getElementById("moneda");
        let valor = moneda.value;
        let valores = [2, 1, 0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01];
        let resultado = cambio(valor, valores);
        i = 0;
        let respuesta = "Deben devolverse: ";
        resultado.forEach(function (e) {
            if (e != 0) {
                v = valores[i];
                respuesta += (e + (e == 1 ? " moneda de " : " monedas de ") + v + (v == 1 ? " euro, " : " euros, "));
            }
            i++;
        });
        respuesta = respuesta.substring(0, respuesta.length - 2);
        console.log(respuesta);
    })
</script>
```

Para devolver 2.34, muestra en consola:

```
Deben devolverse: 1 moneda de 2 euros, 1 moneda de 0.2 euros, 1 moneda de 0.1 euros, 2 monedas de 0.02 euros
```

Para devolver 5, muestra en consola:

```
Deben devolverse: 2 monedas de 2 euros, 1 moneda de 1 euro
```